# VSCode aggressively deletes all code after unconditional return (no-unreachable)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes I have code like this:

```
function x() {
  func1();
  func2();
  func3();
}
```

and when I'm debugging I put a return on the third line if I don't want/care about `func2`/`func3`:

```
function x() {
  func1();
  return;
  
  func2();
  func3();
}
```

On save, VSCode very rudely deletes `func2` and `func3`!!! Yes I know it is unreachable code, but I am only adding that return there temporarily. A yellow underline would be nice. I can't seem to turn it off. Is there any way to turn it off or am I using it wrong? It seems like a really silly and overzealous feature to me.

Comment: What formatter do you use?

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like something to do with the "on save" feature of whatever formatter you're using.

Comment: Maybe you should use `if(true) return;` - does that trick the thing into leaving it alone?  Otherwise `#ifndef NEVER return; #endif` should work because VS Code has no idea if NEVER will exist at some point.

Comment: No, I have to use if (Math.random() > 1). Yeah I use prettier, maybe it's that

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Seems to be eslint's problem, as when I turn off `"source.fixAll": true,` in `settings.json`, it doesn't happen. I can't figure out how to turn off that rule though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue.

In `settings.json` (`~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`)

I had:

```
"source.fixAll": true,
```

changing this to

```
"source.fixAll.eslint": true,
```

Stops the editor removing the unreachable code unnecessarily

Comment: thank you sir. begs the question, if that rule is not coming from eslint, where is it coming from though?

Comment: This comes from TypeScript by default not allowing unreachable code, combined with `formatOnSave` being set to true. You can either turn off `formatOnSave` (less ideal), or you can turn off unreachable code checks by adding `"allowUnreachableCode": true` in `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 2):

Set `allowUnreachableCode: true` in `tsconfig.json`.